# Implementing Stacked HTML Tags in Own Rich Text Editor, Preventing Overwriting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on my rich editor.

There's a text area when the user enter text, for example

```
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Then, the editor selects with the mouse the fragment that he wants, for example, bold. The button is clicked, and the text is modified into:

```
<b>lorem</b> ipsum dolor sit amet
```

or
**lorem** ipsum dolor sit amet

The modified text with HTML tags will be stored in the database and then used.
The problem is when the editor want to bold, for example, the second word:

lorem **ipsum** dolor sit amet

Instead of:

**lorem** **ipsum** dolor sit amet

The first modification is reset, and the newest is applied. I decided to store all the modified fragments in an array. So, every time a text is modified, a selected fragment with HTML tags is in an array:

```
['<b>lorem</b>','<b>ipsum</b>']
```

Now, should I iterate through this and compare somehow the modified and original text, and then replace the original text with modified fragments?

Also, I don't know to prevent the tags from doubling   on the same text.

```
const fullText =  // full text entered by the user
const selectedText = // selected text by mouse
const modifiedText = // selectedText text with tags for example <b> lorem </b>
const modifiedFullText =  // text to be saved in database with html tags
const formattedFragments = r // array with formatted fragments
```

I made a lot of variables to separate different levels of the process. Still, I don't know how to do it.
In the next step, I will try to add toggling, but now I'm trying to make it work on the simplest example.

```
 formattedFragments.value.forEach((fragment) => {
    console.log(`${fragment}`)
    modifiedFullText.value = modifiedFullText.value.replace(selectedText.value, fragment)
```

Still, it doesn't work. In the text, only the newest modification is applied.

Comment: good luck, this is very hard to build, see WYSIWYG component library, such as [this](https://www.coffeecup.com/html-editor/) or [collection](https://www.tecmint.com/wysiwyg-html-editors/)

Comment: thanks sir; i want to make it very simple with basic functionality; i just want to toggle between adding and removing some simple tags, i wish i will make it work;

Comment: also i tried Quill and TipTap, but they are very confusing to work with.

Comment: take a look at their code, its open source. and reverse engineer how they are doing it, then just borrow some of the methods they use